# Initializing single element of string array into another string variable in Go lang

Tags: arrays, string, variables, go

In this code, I read a text file for input (A1,B2) and Im using the split function to separate them at comma and store in strs, according to the function definition its returns a array in this case it is strs array, i want the first element in strs to be in currentSource and the second element to be in CurrentDest.I tried printing both the variables individually to check if its working,but the program exits after that and  I get a error saying Panic: index out of range. 
Can anybody help me out..!!!

```
var currentSource string
var currentDest string

func main() {

    file, err := os.Open("chessin.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        strs := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), ",")

        currentSource = strs[0]
        currentDest = strs[1]
}
```

Comment: You should tag your language as well. :)

Comment: `strings.Split` does not returns an array but a slice of strings. And you have to actually check if `len(strs) >= 2`. What's the content of the file?

Comment: OH right..!! So...How do i assign slice values to currentSource and currentDest variables and the content of the file is multiple statements like C3,F3,C4,A4,C5,A1 @KavehShahbazian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
var currentSource string
var currentDest string

func main() {

    file := "A1,B2\n"
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(file))
    for scanner.Scan() {
        strs := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), ",")

        currentSource = strs[0]
        currentDest = strs[1]

        fmt.Println(strs)
    }


}
```

Are you sure your file (`chessin.txt`) it is ok?

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/r-9FGaaJBZ)

Comment: The task for me was to read the input from a text file and yes im very sure  that it is fine, I dont understand why is it showing that error , the values are assigned correctly, but the program exits after that. As mentioned in the previous question I will wait, I'm just looking for more help no offence @Toni Villena

Comment: @Riya , I don't have offended, sorry if you thought that... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code is almost the same as your code and it works correctly:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var currentSource string
var currentDest string

func main() {

    // content of this file is (no spaces between comas, not \r or
    // \n or any other whitespace):
    //C3,F3,C4,A4,C5,A1
    file, err := os.Open("chessin.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        strs := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), ",")

        if len(strs) < 2 {
            panic(`not enough elements in the file, to proceed`)
        }

        currentSource = strs[0]
        currentDest = strs[1]

        break //(B)
    }

    if currentSource != "C3" {
        panic(`currentSource IS NOT C3`)
    }

    if currentDest != "F3" {
        panic(`currentDest is not F3`)
    }

    // if we are here, then we are good
    fmt.Println(currentSource, currentDest)
}
```

Just pay attention to the `break` statement at *(B)*. That causes the `for` loop to stop, after the first and second elements of the first line - not sure; but that might be what you want.

So, if the program does not reach the *(A)* point, then there something wrong with `chessin.txt`.